# im want to embed Clutch.co widget into my next js web project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When i embed code of clutch.co widget and render it on the main page it shows me " Hydration failed error"

this is the code of the widget from clutch.co:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.clutch.co/static/js/widget.js"></script> 

<div class="clutch-widget" data-url="https://widget.clutch.co" data-widget-type="3" data-height="320" data-nofollow="true" data-expandifr="true" data-scale="100" data-reviews="2220706,2123032,2113547" data-clutchcompany-id="2108125"></div>
```

i have created a component named ClutchWidget.js and its code is:

```
"use client";

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function ClutchWidget() {
  const [showWidget, setShowWidget] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://widget.clutch.co/static/js/widget.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    // Set showWidget to true after component mounts

    setShowWidget(true);

    // Clean up

    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {showWidget && (
        <div
          className="clutch-widget"
          data-url="https://widget.clutch.co"
          data-widget-type="3"
          data-height="320"
          data-nofollow="true"
          data-expandifr="true"
          data-scale="100"
          data-reviews="2220706,2123032,2113547"
          data-clutchcompany-id="2108125"
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClutchWidget;
```

when i render this component on Page.js. i see nothing on homepage

Other approach i tried was:

i copied  element in Layout.js as:

```
import "./globals.css";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.clutch.co/static/js/widget.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and created a component as ClutchWidget.js:

```
import React from "react";

function ClutchWidget() {
  <div
    className="clutch-widget"
    data-url="https://widget.clutch.co"
    data-widget-type="3"
    data-height="320"
    data-nofollow="true"
    data-expandifr="true"
    data-scale="100"
    data-reviews="2220706,2123032,2113547"
    data-clutchcompany-id="2108125"
  />;
}

export default ClutchWidget;
```

and trying to render it in main page (page.js) as:

```
import ClutchWidget from "./components/Testimonials/ClutchWidget";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ClutchWidget />
    </div>
  );
}
```

but still widget is not rendering. HELP!

Comment: howdy - well done _ this is very inspiiring. well -can we do some inclusion into a wordpress-widget to. that would be more than awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Clutch script ends with

```
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (e) {
  "loading" !== e.target.readyState && !1 === window.CLUTCHCO.loaded && window.CLUTCHCO.Init();
});
```

so it will only execute initialization after the document finishes loading, but not afterwards.

As you can see, there'll be a `window.CLUTCHCO.Init()` function you can call after the script has finished loading.

For a lazy, non-robust approach, add

```
setTimeout(() => window.CLUTCHCO.init(), 500);
```

somewhere and hope the script has had the chance to load in 500 milliseconds.

Comment: Can you tell me where should i add the code you wrote above ?

Comment: In the `useEffect` where you load the script.

Comment: thanks for the help,i want to ask you one more thing about the second approach/method i tried above. widget is rendering in that case but give me warning of " Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server. & Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a <iframe> in <div>." can you help me in this ?

Comment: howdy - well done _ this is very inspiiring. well -can we do some inclusion into a wordpress-widget to. that would be more than awesome.